# Seeing symmetries

Tags: group-theory, symmetry, visualization

#### Preliminaries

Let $[n] = \{0,\dots,n-1\}$ and $P([n])$ be the power set of $[n]$.

Let the correlation between two subsets $x,y$ of $[n]$ be the number $\kappa(x,y) = 1 - \frac{2}{n}|x\triangle y|$ with $x\triangle y$ the symmetric difference between $x$ and $y$.

$\kappa$ measures how strongly $x, y$ do agree in terms of their members and non-members, from $\kappa=1$ for $x=y$ to $\kappa=-1$ when $x$ and $y$ are complements of each other. When $|x\triangle y|=n/2$ the sets $x,y$ are uncorrelated, $\kappa = 0$.

#### Question

I wonder how, why and under which circumstances it is possible to literally *see* the symmetries of a structure (or at least some of them), and how to interpret systematically what is seen.

As a non-trivial example consider the **correlation graph** $(V,E)$ of the powerset $P([8]) =: V$ where $(x,y)\in E$ when $\kappa(x,y) \neq 0$.

Some symmetries of this graph are due to the fact that for every permutation $\pi$ of $\{0,\dots,7\}$ it holds that $\kappa(x,y) =  \kappa(\pi(x),\pi(y))$. Further, the graph is invariant against complements, since $\kappa(x,y) =  \kappa(\overline{x},\overline{y})$

Many more symmetries can be seen in one of the 256x256 adjacency matrices of the graph:

[image]

To see some kind of translational symmetries it is helpful to bend this square to a torus. Then it is also seen, that on the highest level the pattern consists of two pairs of symmetric squares:

[image]

On a lower level, it consists of five smaller symmetric squares:

[image]

On an even lower level, it consists of two symmetric squares:

[image]

Even lower, it consists of three symmetric squares:

[image]

Even lower, it consists of two symmetric squares:

[image]

Finally we find, that it consists of only two tiny symmetric squares:

[image]

> **Question 1:** Are there other than the canonical labeling of the elements of $V$ (by [Ackermann encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIT_predicate) which was used for the adjacency matrix above) that show the symmetries to the
> eye? If not so: How can I understand that it is essentially this
> labeling that has this property?
>
> **Question 2:** How can these visual observations be put in correspondence to abstract facts about the automorphism group of the
> graph, including its size?
>
> **Question 3:** To which visible symmetries corresponds the invariance of the graph with respect to permutations of $\{0,\dots,7\}$ and with respect to complements?
>
> **Question 4:** How might an algorithm look like that - given a scrambled adjacency matrix (without any visible symmetries) - finds a
> sequence of transpositions that lead to the unscrambled matrix above?
> (see Rubik's cube)

Comment: Um, $x\triangle y \ne \varnothing$ exactly when $x\ne y$, and that's not the graph you're drawing.

Comment: Sorry for that, I fixed the question.